# Is it possible to connect to mysql from the library so?

Tags: c++, mysql, c, dll, shared-libraries

When writing one of my first plugins for an external application I encountered a large obstruction.
Plugins are loaded as DLL files (SO for linux)
Attempts to connect to the database, but it requires some other compilation.
Everywhere write that it is necessary to compile applications using a given command:

```
gcc exa_7.c -o exa_7 -std=c99  `mysql_config --cflags --libs'
```

The command is the most correct, but I can't combine to the attributes: `-c -fPIC`

When I try to fire code without passing the attributes necessary for MYSQL, it causes me a lot of errors:

```
dllmain.c:46:5: error: unknown type name ‘MYSQL’; did you mean ‘MYSQL_XID’?
     MYSQL      *MySQLConRet;
     ^~~~~
     MYSQL_XID
dllmain.c:47:5: error: unknown type name ‘MYSQL’; did you mean ‘MYSQL_XID’?
     MYSQL      *MySQLConnection = NULL;
     ^~~~~
     MYSQL_XID
dllmain.c:74:5: error: unknown type name ‘MYSQL_RES’; did you mean ‘MYSQL_XID’?
     MYSQL_RES      *mysqlResult = NULL;
     ^~~~~~~~~
     MYSQL_XID
dllmain.c:90:6: error: unknown type name ‘MYSQL_ROW’; did you mean ‘MYSQL_XID’?
      MYSQL_ROW       mysqlRow;
      ^~~~~~~~~
      MYSQL_XID
dllmain.c:91:6: error: unknown type name ‘MYSQL_FIELD’; did you mean ‘MYSQL_XID’?
      MYSQL_FIELD    *mysqlFields;
      ^~~~~~~~~~~
      MYSQL_XID
```

My list includes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <mysql/mysql.h>
#include <mysql/my_global.h>
#include <mysql/my_config.h>
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include "ts3_functions.h"
#include "plugin.h"
#include <pthread.h>
//(more includes, but not important)
```

Do you have any idea how to solve this?

//EDIT:
delete comment for `#include <mysql/mysql.h>`

Now I compiled it with the command: `gcc -pthread -c -fPIC -o test.o dllmain.c`

The compilation runs correctly (without any errors), but when running the program gets the message:`undefined symbol: mysql_init`

Maybe problem is in code?:

```
MYSQL      *MySQLConRet;
MYSQL      *MySQLConnection = NULL;

MySQLConnection = mysql_init( NULL );
MySQLConRet = mysql_real_connect( MySQLConnection,
                                  hostName, 
                                  userId, 
                                  password, 
                                  DB, 
                                  0, 
                                  NULL,
                                  0 );

if ( MySQLConRet == NULL ) {
    printf(mysql_error(MySQLConnection) );
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: Why is the `#include` for `<mysql/mysql.h>` commented out?

Comment: You're right. My mistake XD
But still not working properly mysql. The compilation is currently running, but it gets an error on startup: **undefined symbol: mysql_init**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't included `<mysql/mysql.h>`. Uncomment that line. This file is required to use the MySQL API. `<mysql/my_global.h>` is an internal header used to include common system header files and define utility macros -- it is *not* a substitute for `<mysql/mysql.h>`, and should not be included directly at all.